# Is there a way to see which groups/users have access to an RSA key container?

Tags: rsa, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I used `aspnet_regiis` to create an RSA key container (machine container).

I want to secure it and I know I can use the `-pa` and `-pr` commands to specify access.  But is there a way to see which accounts/groups have access to it?

My concern is I created a container that is basically an open book that anyone can access on this machine and get the private key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Machine Keys are stored in: `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys`

They have normal file permissions, you can view as you'd like. Be careful changing permissions, they're easy to screw up.

Comment: You are my hero, the wind beneath my wings.  Not sure why this eluded me -- I was aware of this storage location but for some reason I was thinking these key containers were "magic".  Thank you!

Comment: The files in this folder have hex-formatted names, so how do I find a key container with specific name? Any idea?